# Uncaught TypeError: users.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, material-ui

I'm using data grid in material ui.

I want to create a row as much as data from params.

example: `(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]` ← from `User.includes(:evaluations).where(user_evaluations: { evaluation_id: 6 }).order('users.updated_at DESC')`

So I came up that best solution is using map method.

But I got the following error..

```
Uncaught TypeError: users.map is not a function
```

The code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_ENDPOINT}/admin/users`, {
        headers: {
          "access-token": access_token!,
          client: client!,
          uid: uid!,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.created_at);
        console.log(response.data.data);
        setUsers(response.data.data);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        dispatch(setSessionTimeout(true));
        dispatch(setLoggedIn(false));
        navigate("/");
      });
  }, []);

  const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 70 },
  ];

  const rows = users.map((row: any) => ({
    id: row.id,
  }));

...
    <DataGrid
       rows={users}
       columns={columns}
       checkboxSelection
       className={classes.data_grid_styles}
       pageSize={pageSize}
       rowsPerPageOptions={[15, 30, 50]}
       onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) =>
       setPageSize(newPageSize)
       }/>
```

content of `response.data.data` is:

```
0: {id: 1392, email: 'yuuyake91922211111@yahoo.co.jp', image: null, name_sei: 'テストああ', name_mei: 'name', …} 1: {id: 1391, email: 'yuuyake91911111@yahoo.co.jp', image: null, name_sei: 'テスト', name_mei: 'name', …} 2: {id: 1387, email: 'yuuyake9191asss@yahoo.co.jp', image: null, name_sei: 'あ', name_mei: 'あ', …} length: 3 [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

What the code wrong is?

And if you know better solution about:

> So I came up that best solution is using map method.

Let me know.
Please help me..

Comment: The received `Users` is not an array. Maybe an object or `null/undefined`.

Comment: Please update with what `response.data.data` holds there. Maybe it should be `setUsers(response.data);`

Comment: >SelvaS
Users is not null...

Comment: >razvans
I tried `setUsers(response.data);` but the result didn't change at all..
content of `response.data.data` is: `0: {id: 1392, email: 'yuuyake91922211111@yahoo.co.jp', image: null, name_sei: 'テストああ', name_mei: 'name', …}
1: {id: 1391, email: 'yuuyake91911111@yahoo.co.jp', image: null, name_sei: 'テスト', name_mei: 'name', …}
2: {id: 1387, email: 'yuuyake9191asss@yahoo.co.jp', image: null, name_sei: 'あ', name_mei: 'あ', …}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)`

How can I fix it...

Comment: also I got this error at the same time... `Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop rows of type object supplied to ForwardRef, expected an array.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it!!

Before:

`const [users, setUsers] = React.useState(Object);`

After:

`const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([]);`